# I am creating a simple calculator in switch statement using methods but it straight goes to default, even if i press correct case

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, calculator

I am making this simple calculator program using switch statements and methods. But when the user presses any option (which is correct), it does not read the case and goes straight to the default case.

I've done the same thing before, but without any class file or methods. I'm new to methods so  I just tried to do the same thing but it's not working properly.

```
    NewClass cal = new NewClass();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Division.\nPress 2 for Multiplication.\nPress 3 for Addition.\nPress 4 for Substraction.");
    char c = in.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter First Value : ");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Value : ");
    int b = in.nextInt();
    switch (c){
        case 1:
            cal.division(a, b);
            break;
        case 2:
           cal.division(a, b);
            break;
        case 3:
            cal.add(a, b);
            break;
        case 4:
            cal.sub(a, b);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
            break;
    }
```

output:

```
Press 1 for Division.
Press 2 for Multiplication.
Press 3 for Addition.
Press 4 for Substraction.
Enter your selection : 3
Enter First Value : 
4
Enter Second Value : 
5
Invalid entry.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert user input to a char, as java switches can handle ints.  The following code will fix your issue:

```
NewClass cal = new NewClass();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Division.\nPress 2 for Multiplication.\nPress 3 for Addition.\nPress 4 for Substraction.");
    int c = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter First Value : ");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Value : ");
    int b = in.nextInt();
    switch (c){
        case 1:
            cal.division(a, b);
            break;
        case 2:
           cal.division(a, b);
            break;
        case 3:
            cal.add(a, b);
            break;
        case 4:
            cal.sub(a, b);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you guys are best <3.